# Getting top-level folders in AWS S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, directory

I understand that the concept of "folder" does not exist in AWS S3 and that everything is merely a pair of key & value. This is actually an issue for me because I have implemented a class to work with S3 to access files and folders. To get the list of folders I have to fetch the list of all keys (which may be about 50,000 objects) and find out the folders based on the position of '/' character.

I searched the Internet to find an easier way of doing so but I did not find anything. However when I run "S3 Browser" I see that it can very quickly list the folder names. I tried to sniff the network and see what S3 API is used by S3 Browser and how but since S3 Browser uses SSL I did not go anywhere.

Can you please let me know if I can somehow find out all the kes in S3 which represent a folder?

Example:

```
/F1/
/F1/F1_1/
/F1/F1_1/F1_2
/F1/F1_1/F1_2/File1.ZIP
/F1/F1_2/F1_2/File2.ZIP
/F2/
/F2/F1
```

I want to be able to get /F1/ and /F2/ quickly without having to retrieve the subdirectories and files.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When we pass delimiter parameter as slash ("/") in `ListObjectsV2Async`
method, it will group keys with the same prefix together, and will emulate folder structure

```
var listRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Prefix = prefix, // set root or targeted folder here
    Delimiter = "/"; // Set delimiter as "/"
};

using var client = new AmazonS3Client();
var response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(listRequest);

// Access "CommonPrefixes" list for folder names
var folderNames = response.CommonPrefixes.Select(p => p.Prefix).ToList();
```

This is much more efficient than listing all objects and filtering based on slashes in all S3 Keys.

- You may remove prefix from response to get only folder name
- Use `Prefix` property to get sub folders of specific parent path/folder as key.